# could not find function "cast" despite reshape2 installed and loaded

Tags: r, reshape2

In following Hadley Wickham's ["Practical tools for exploring data and models"](http://had.co.nz/thesis/) examples in section 2.4, *Casting molten data* I'm getting `Error: could not find function "cast"`. I have the reshape2 package installed and loaded.

```
> cast(msmithsm, time + subject ~ variable)
Error: could not find function "cast"
```

Comment: Could you post your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: `> sessioninfo()
Error: could not find function "sessioninfo"`

Comment: Not that you need to run it here, but that has to be `sessionInfo()` (not `sessioninfo()`).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In **reshape2**, `cast()` has been replaced by *two* functions: `acast()` and `dcast()`.

From `?cast`, in package **reshape2**:

> Description:
>
> Use ‘acast’ or ‘dcast’ depending on whether you want
>      vector/matrix/array output or data frame output.

Comment: Seems kind of crazy that ?cast works & does not explicitly note that `cast` does not exist!

Comment: @DrewSteen -- I guess in this case, `?cast` is more like `?Arithmetic` or `?Startup`, describing a topic rather than a function.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I think the documentation would be improved by either explicitly noting that `cast` - the way it reads, it is easy to come away understanding that `acast` and `dcast` are related alternative functions.

Answer (score 2):

Had related issue (Error: could not find function "dcast"). I had old library, library(plyr), so just added to code...

```
install.packages("reshape2") # may already be installed
library(reshape2)
```

Then dcast worked again